# Livewire wire:model not working with nested components

Tags: php, laravel-livewire

I'm creating a page using livewire to list users from DB and be able to update them..
I have a Users parent component and (User)s child components

users.blade.php:

```
<div>
    @foreach($users as $key => $user)
        <livewire:user :user="$user" key="{{$user->id}}">
    @endforeach
</div>
```

user.blade.php

```
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="save">
        <input type="text" wire:model="user.name">
        <input type="text" wire:model="user.email">
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Users.php

```
class Users extends Component
{
    public $users;
    
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->users = User::all();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.users');
    }
}
```

User.php

```
class User extends Component
{
    public $user;

    public function mount(\App\Models\User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user');
    }

    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:6',
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ];

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate();
        $user = $this->user;
        User::find($user['id'])->fill([
            'name' => $user['name'],
            'email' => $user['email']
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is what i'm getting in the browser

[image]

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Have you added `@livewireScripts` to your layout? If yes, try to clear the cache.

Comment: yes I did but still no working, Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was the validation rules, I had to change it to

```
protected $rules = [
    'user.name' => 'required|min:6',
    'user.email' => 'required|email',
];
```